# How to get node info by 30303 port?

Tags: node-discovery, devp2p, enode, discovery-protocol, rlpx

I need to create something like [ethernodes.org](https://ethernodes.org) or [etherscan.io/nodetracker](https://etherscan.io/nodetracker). First of all, I tried to implement *Discovery Protocol* by own, but after couple of minutes I realized that [specs](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/discv4.md) are too hard to implement.

How can I easily get node info using external **enode** (30303) port?

Comment: Can't you just use gRPC and use the admin module? https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0-alpha/web3-eth-admin.html#getnodeinfo

Comment: I need to get info of not my node. As you know - I can't get access to RPC (especially **admin** module). So I need to use *Node Discovery Protocol* with **30303** port.